# How to filter out documents in mongodb, based on multiple conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

given the following collection of items:

```
-> {type" : "WIRE",  subtype" : "RETURN", "amount" : 3500, "gid" : 2975075},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "INCOME", "amount" : 1750, gid" : 2975075},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 1750, "gid" : 2975075},
-> {"type" : "WIRE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 3500,"gid" : 2975075},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "INCOME", "amount" : 0.08, "gid" : 2895112},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 0.08, "gid" : 2895112},
{"type" : "WIRE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 5, "gid" : 2895112, }
```

How do I filter out/exclude the marked records?

I have tried several solutions but none of them worked, such as:
db.collection.find({$and:[{type:{$ne:"WIRE"}},{subtype:{$nin:["RETURN","TXN"]}},{gid:{$ne:2975075}}]})

Expected result:

```
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "INCOME", "amount" : 1750, gid" : 2975075},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 1750, "gid" : 2975075},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "INCOME", "amount" : 0.08, "gid" : 2895112},
{"type" : "FEE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 0.08, "gid" : 2895112},
{"type" : "WIRE", "subtype" : "TXN", "amount" : 5, "gid" : 2895112, }
```

Comment: Can you show the attempts that you tried to the question?

Comment: What are these "several solutions"? What is the condition to show or exclude the documents?

Comment: db.collection.find({$and:[{type:{$ne:"WIRE"}},{subtype:{$nin:["RETURN","TXN"]}},{gid:{$ne:2975075}}]})

Comment: The rule is to get all items except the items where the type is "WIRE" , subtype is either "RETURN "or "TXN " AND the gid is 2975075

Answer (score 0):

We can only make assumptions based on what you want the filtering rules to be, but I would assume you want to filter and keep only records that have an `amount` of less than `3000`, or something that effect.

You want to use a [find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query and filter items that have an amount [less than of equal to - $lte](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) any given value. Something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rSjMJ2WsO7V

```
db.collection.find({
  amount: {
    $lte: 3000
  }
})
```

Now that you've clarified the rules, another example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZblkiU3q5m7

```
db.collection.find({
  $nor: [
    {
      type: "WIRE",
      subtype: {
        $in: [
          "RETURN",
          "TXN"
        ]
      },
      gid: 2975075
    }
  ]
})
```

Note: I think you found this difficult because you were getting mixed between $and, $nor and $in, $nin. You want to filter out documents ($nor, even just for a single condition), the you have to match sure that the filter includes ($in) the values you want to filter. There are a number of double negatives that makes it hard to read your requirements, but this looks to be the simplest expression of what you want.

Comment: The rule is to get all items except the items where the type is "WIRE" , subtype is either "RETURN "or "TXN " AND the gid is 2975075

Comment: Updated now that you've added you criteria.